# How to implement unique alphanum Authentication using Azure Mobile App Service?

Tags: ios, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

How do i implement unique alphanum auth in my ios mobile app using azure, i sort of did this by inserting a unique alphanum value in one of the SQLServer database **user** tables and when the user enters the unique code in the UI i check in the backend if the value is valid and let him in, but how can i really restrict the tables to only Authenticated users in the database? I am also not able to make my app build using username and password in Azure Auth since it only supports AD,Microsoft,FB and Twitter. Can anyone help me in this regard?

[unique-code-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hSpl.png)

[permissions_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLaZu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Be able to make my app build using username and password in Azure Auth

By default, as you said above, it only supports AD, Microsoft, FireBase and Twitter. So we need to do this by ourselves. We need to add authentication feature via writing code in backend project. There are two type of backend we can use: .NET and Node.js, for more information about backend SDK, we can refer to:

[.NET Backend SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/overview/azure/mobileapps/client?view=azure-dotnet)

[Azure Mobile Apps - Node SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/)

> > how can i really restrict the tables to only Authenticated users in the database

We need to do this at Backend: [Restrict permissions to authenticated users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-users#permissions)

Comment: This is very helpful. Let me try, thank you Lee Liu.

Comment: @Liu can you provide a sample code? I am using Objective C and i am not sure where to put this authentication code.

Comment: I am sorry for that i am not familiar with OC, you can post a new thread to ask this question in OC scope.

Answer (score 0):

Lee Liu just provided some common tutorials about Azure Mobile Apps. Based on my experience, you could build your custom provider instead of the build-in identity providers to implement your requirement.

> I am also not able to make my app build using username and password in Azure Auth since it only supports AD,Microsoft,FB and Twitter. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Based on your description, I assumed that you are using the [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). If the build-in identity providers could not meet your requirement, you could also build your own custom identity provider (e.g. username/password against your database,etc) and you could also leverage the features provided by App Service Authentication /Authorization (Easy Auth).

For achieving this approach, you could follow [How to: Use custom authentication for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth) for .NET backend. Moreover, you could follow adrian hall's blog about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) for detailed tutorial. For NodeJS backend, you could follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/).

Comment: Thank you very much Bruce Chen. Your answer is very valuable for the project that i am working on.

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help you. Any problems, feel free to let me know.

Comment: @Chen would you be able to help me with a sample code i am trying to follow this https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/ but i want to use unique key to login as username and password. Can i achieve this using Nodejs?